# Calculation of third vertices of a triangle given a vector that should be perpendicular to the triangle plane

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have an isosceles triangle (2 sides same length) with vertices O, A and B. OA and OB are the same length.

Vertices O and A are known, with O at origin (0,0,0).

A known vector V, should be perpendicular to the plane formed by the triangle.

Calculate vertices B.

This is the opposite of the fairly easy calculation of determining the perpendicular vector to the plane of a triangle, which is calculated by the dot product of the vectors OA and OB.

Comment: Can't you create a triangle with $O$, $A$ and $V$ such as $OB$ is perpendicular to the plane of this triangle?

Comment: I can get a vector that is perpendicular to the plane but how to get B from there is what I am struggling with

Comment: You have $O$, the length $OB$ and you can compute a vector with direction $OB$. I think you can finish it

Answer (score 0):

With the given data, there isn't that much to say about the vertex $B$. What we can say, is where $B$ might be. When given a vector $v$, we can find the perpendicular plane through the origin and know that all of $O$, $A$ and $B$ lie in this plane. Since $OA=OB$, all possibilities for $B$ lie on a circle in this plane with centre $O$ and radius $OA$. (In case one does not want to consider degenerate triangles, the points $A$ and $-A$ should be removed.)

It might be a somewhat different story, though, if the length of the perpendicular somehow depends on the angle $\angle AOB$, but I don't see any mention of this being the case in the question.

Comment: B is defined by the length AB which is given and not arbitrary.  The problem is to determine the position of point B to satisfy the requirement that OAB would be perpendicular to the vector V.

Comment: That's good to know, since the original statement doesn't mention that $AB$ is given. With the knowledge of $v$, perpendicular to the plane of the triangle, the points $O$ and $A$ and the fact that $OA=OB$, knowing $AB$, the point $B$ still will not be unique though. If we assume, for instance, $v=(0,0,1)$ (so the triangle lies in the $xy$-plane), $A=(0,1,0)$, $AB=\sqrt{2}$, the point $B$ may still be either of $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks HSN. Can you provide a general form that would work for all instances, even if the general form provides two results?  Test with for say Thanks for the reply.  Lets assume OA = 6, AB=6 and AB=4.1. (Angle AOB=40). Take point A = (-4.32,3.53,2.22) and V=(0.34, -0.16, 0.93). Calculate B. Graphically in a CAD I can determine the value of B as B=(-0.98, 5.76, 1.38).